# using and clause on multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the below query that looks in columns `DET_NOMINALDR` and `DET_NOMINALCR` for items that have `60%` and `%10%` in.

On column may not have this criteria in and the other one will (and vice versa) but I want to find these criteria even if the other column doesn't have it in (I hope that makes sense!!)

This query seems to work as it is, however, it is completely ignoring the first two `WHERE` clauses and will find items that aren't `det_year = 'C'` and `DET_PERIODNUMBR = '4'`

I'm guessing it's got something to do with the brackets? Or probably something else I'm overlooking, but any help would be appreciated!

```
select * from sl_pl_nl_detail
where det_year = 'C'
and DET_PERIODNUMBR = '4'
and DET_NOMINALDR like '60%' and DET_NOMINALDR like '%10%'
or (DET_NOMINALCR like '60%' and DET_NOMINALCR like '%10%')
```

Comment: Seems like you need more parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND` goes before `OR`. Move your parentheses:

```
select * from sl_pl_nl_detail
where det_year = 'C'
  and DET_PERIODNUMBR = '4'
  and (DET_NOMINALDR like '60%' and DET_NOMINALDR like '%10%'
    or DET_NOMINALCR like '60%' and DET_NOMINALCR like '%10%')
```

Comment: perfect, thanks this works...I just put the brackets in the wrong place